# Return only specif element of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm parsing some information using JSON

And after calling `Json.projectStatus.status` I receive one of two responses : (`ERROR` or `OK`)

And I want only to display `ERROR` status :

```
function search(projectKey, projectName, lastAnalysis) {
    var url = "https://***?projectKey=" + projectKey;
    request(
        {
            url : url,
            headers : {
                "Authorization" : auth
            }
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                process(body, projectName, lastAnalysis);
            }
        }
    );
}

function process(response, projectName, lastAnalysis){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var color = "#6f6f68";
    var description = "";
    if (Json.projectStatus.status == "ERROR") {
        color = "#FA4643";
        description = ", Errors: ";
        var Data = Json.projectStatus.conditions.map(function(status) {

            if (status.actualValue > 0) {
                description = description 
                            + status.actualValue 
                            + " " + status.metricKey 
                            + ", ";
            }
        });
    }
    var project = {
        name: projectName, 
        status: Json.projectStatus.status,    // Filter only "error"
        color:color, 
        lastAnalysis:lastAnalysis, 
        description
    };
    Projects.push(project);
    counter++;
    if (counter == numberProjects) {
        parse();
    }
}
```

JSON response (example)

```
{"projectStatus":{"status":"ERROR","conditions":..}}
{"projectStatus":{"status":"OK","conditions":..}}
{"projectStatus":{"status":"ERROR","conditions"...}}
{"projectStatus":{"status":"ERROR","conditions":..}}
{"projectStatus":{"status":"OK","conditions":..}}
```

Actual result (example):

- `ERROR`
- `OK`
- `ERROR`
- `ERROR`
- `OK`

expected result (example):

- `ERROR`
- `ERROR`
- `ERROR`

Comment: push it to `Projects` only if `project.status == "ERROR"`

Comment: What's the point of the `var Data =` and `map`? You never return anything from the callback.

Comment: Put var project until parse();} inside the if above them

Comment: thanks for your help @CalvinNunes

Comment: Yes sorry i'm trying to do something but forget to comment it 
Thanks @Bergi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(Json.projectStatus.status == "ERROR"){
  Projects.push(project);
}
```